# Historical Accounting Lines in Sabre PNR

Tags: web-services, soap, sabre

Is there any API that Sabre has or plans to expose that returns historical accounting lines from a PNR?

Parsing the HAC display in text is painful. Relying on the AC lines within a PNR is inaccurate since they may be removed at any time.

Comment: Are you using the host command to pull the HAC? Maybe the history API would be better parsed.

However we loop through the ticket list with WTDB via host command for accounting. Cannot remove the ticket list, and WTDB has all the information in the accounting lines, and then some (a lot). I find it the most wholesome and reliable method

Comment: Yeah, I am using the host command now, but thanks to Telmo Paz and you, I'll implement the history API and use that instead, I think that'll work perfectly. Great idea to loop through the ticket list, but my use case is for non-arc invoices that may not be on that list so I need a deeper historical look at all the AC lines that were invoiced.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using TravelItineraryHistoryLLSRQ (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary_History)? That service does parse historical accounting lines.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for this! I only looked at the sample RS payload of that API before I posted my question and it didn't have those elements in it, I should have dug deeper. I think this will work for me!